# How do I find a way to write a a vector as a linear combination of other vectors 3 different ways?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

[image]

So I put this in my augmented matrix:
[image]

And then I find it's reduced echelon form:
[image]

But I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $a,b$ and $c$ such that

$
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}+b
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

This can be turned into a system of equations:

$$3a+b+5c=2$$
$$-a+2b-3c=5$$

Then you used the augmented matrix and obtained that $$a+\frac{13}{7}c=\frac{-1}{7}$$
$$b-\frac{4}{7}c=\frac{17}{7}$$

This means that for any $c$ you choose, you can find $a$ and $b$ such that $
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear combination of the other three matrices.

Indeed, for example choosing $c=1$, then we have $a=-2$ and $b=3$ so checking:

$a\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}+b
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-3\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-6\\
2
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-3\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$

as required.

Comment: Omg it's you again ares <3 thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hey, you're welcome! :-)